# Перебор свойств обьекта и мутация

Tags: javascript, объекты

Подскажите пожалуйста как на js сделать мутацию обьекта.
Имеется такой объект:

```
const data = [
  {
    category: 1,
    item: 10,
  },
  {
    category: 2,
    item: 20,
  },
  {
    category: 2,
    item: 30,
  },
  {
    category: 3,
    item: 40,
  },
  {
    category: 1,
    item: 50,
  },
  {
    category: 3,
    item: 60,
  },
]
```

Каким образом можно мутировать его в такой обьект?

```
const newData = [
  {
    category: 1,
    items: [
      { item: 10 },
      { item: 50 },
    ]
  },
  {
    category: 2,
    items: [
      { item: 20 },
      { item: 30 },
    ]
  },
  {
    category: 3,
    items: [
      { item: 40 },
      { item: 60 },
    ]
  }
]
```

Душевной благодарю все кто помог! Хорошего дня

Comment: А что значит "мутировать"?

Comment: Создать второй обьект newData путем мутирования или преобразования обьекта data

Comment: Мутирования — как? В ужасного мутанта? :-\

Comment: Если ты разбираешься в вопросе так же как и шутишь то помоги по пожалуйста